# “in a few days” vs. “a few days later”

Tags: word-choice, word-meaning

What’s the difference between “in a few days” and “a few days later”? Thanks.

1. You can receive the product in a few days.
2. You can receive the product a few days later.

Comment: I think they are about the same, but I can't quite decide if that's true in all uses. Can you propose some sample sentences to make the question more concrete?

Comment: I found the second sentence on a book, and wonder if the first is fine too.

Comment: Yes, there's nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are the same. Both are correct actually. 
In modern usage, you often hear people using "a few days later" at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. Your answer seems to imply that people use "a few days later" more commonly than the other at the beginning of a sentence.